# How to fast paralleled Code than nomal Code using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

```cpp
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include "jaehyukTool.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void cpu_PeakFinder(Mat img , Mat* peak);
void cpuMp_PeakFinder(Mat img, Mat* peak);

int main()
{
    /*data set 준비*/
    Mat img = imread("testimg.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC1);
    imgInfo(img);

    /*==========================================================================
    ============================================================================\*/

    /*CPU 실행 코드*/
    /*병렬처리 미사용 코드*/
    {
        Mat peak_cpu(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
        
        system_clock::time_point begin = system_clock::now();
        for (int k = 0; k < 11000; k++)
            cpu_PeakFinder(img, &peak_cpu);

        nanoseconds time = system_clock::now() - begin;
        printf("싱글 스레드 cpu 계산 : %.6lf(ms)\n", time.count() * 1.0E-06);
        transpose(peak_cpu, peak_cpu);
        imshow("peak_cpu", peak_cpu);
    }
    /*==========================================================================
    ============================================================================*/
    {
        /*병렬처리 사용 코드*/
        Mat peak_mp(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
        uchar* ppeakMp = peak_mp.data;

        system_clock::time_point begin = system_clock::now();
        for (int k = 0; k < 11000; k++)
            cpuMp_PeakFinder(img, &peak_mp);

        nanoseconds time = system_clock::now() - begin;
        printf("멀티 스레딩 cpu: %.6lf(ms)\n", time.count() * 1.0E-06);
        transpose(peak_mp, peak_mp);
        imshow("peak_mp", peak_mp);
    }

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}

void cpu_PeakFinder(Mat img, Mat* peak)
{
    uchar* pimg = img.data;
    uchar* ppeak = peak->data;
    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;
    int offset, x, y, row;
    int max, idx;
    for (y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        max = pimg[width * y + 0];
        idx = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            offset = width * y + x;
            if (max < pimg[offset])
            {
                max = pimg[offset];
                idx = offset;
            }
        }
        ppeak[idx] = 255;
    }
}

void cpuMp_PeakFinder(Mat img, Mat* peak)
{
    uchar* pimg = img.data;
    uchar* ppeakMp = peak->data;
    const int width = img.cols;
    const int height = img.rows;
    int offset, x, y;
    int max, idx;

#pragma omp parallel  private(offset) private(max) private(idx) private(x) private(y) num_threads(height)
    {
        y = omp_get_thread_num();
        max = pimg[width * y + 0];
        idx = 0;

        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            offset = width * y + x;
            if (max < pimg[offset])
            {
                max = pimg[offset];
                idx = offset;
            }
        }
        ppeakMp[idx] = 255;
    }
}
```

I want `cpuMp_PeakFinder()` to be faster than `cpu_PeakFinder()`.
But that has not worked as I hoped.

Why is the parallelized code slower?

- I used OpenMp for code parallelization.
- The input is an image of size 64x5120.
- The functions (`cpuMp_PeakFinder()`, `cpu_PeakFinder()`) finds the maximum value of each row.

Comment: First of all: don't measure time with `std::system_clock`, use some real [benchmarking](https://github.com/google/benchmark) library. Second, your example doesn't differ much from other SO questions (google "stack overflow omp slow"), most likely 5000 iterations is not that much for your CPU compared to spawning another thread and sharing the data between cores.

Comment: Using as many threads as there are iterations in a loop, i.e. oversubscribtion is a bad idea for multithreading (GPU offloading is another story). OpenMP has `#pragma omp parallel for` which will automatically cut the loop into as many tiles as there are threads using the default `static` scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the number of threads `num_threads` manually is usually wrong in computational code, as setting them lower or higher than your actual number of cores will penalize your performance, as threads will be contesting on the available cores or underutilizing them.

instead you should rely on `#pragma omp parallel for` to distribute work to the correct number of threads (the total number of threads of your processor).

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
...
}
```

the parallel version is now about twice as fast as the single-thread version.

you may want to play with the blocks in `schedule(dynamic, blocks)` to get the best number of chunks per core, but because the work is very small , twice as fast is the best you can get.

---

MWE with const correctness

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

void cpu_PeakFinder(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& peak);
void cpuMp_PeakFinder(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& peak);

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img(64, 5120, CV_8UC1);
    /*==========================================================================
    ============================================================================\*/

    {
        cv::Mat peak_cpu(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int k = 0; k < 11000; k++)
            cpu_PeakFinder(img, peak_cpu);

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ms]" << std::endl;
        // cv::transpose(peak_cpu, peak_cpu);
        // imshow("peak_cpu", peak_cpu);
    }
    /*==========================================================================
    ============================================================================*/
    {
        cv::Mat peak_mp(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
        uchar *ppeakMp = peak_mp.data;

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int k = 0; k < 11000; k++)
            cpuMp_PeakFinder(img, peak_mp);

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Time difference parallel = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ms]" << std::endl;
        // transpose(peak_mp, peak_mp);
        // imshow("peak_mp", peak_mp);
    }

    // cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}

void cpu_PeakFinder(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& peak)
{
    uchar *pimg = img.data;
    uchar *ppeak = peak.data;
    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;
    int offset, x, y, row;
    int max, idx;
    for (y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        max = pimg[width * y + 0];
        idx = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            offset = width * y + x;
            if (max < pimg[offset])
            {
                max = pimg[offset];
                idx = offset;
            }
        }
        ppeak[idx] = 255;
    }
}

void cpuMp_PeakFinder(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& peak)
{
    uchar *pimg = img.data;
    uchar *ppeakMp = peak.data;
    const int width = img.cols;
    const int height = img.rows;
    int offset, x, y;
    int max, idx;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        max = pimg[width * y + 0];
        idx = 0;

        for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            offset = width * y + x;
            if (max < pimg[offset])
            {
                max = pimg[offset];
                idx = offset;
            }
        }
        ppeakMp[idx] = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"setting the number of threads num_threads manually is wrong"*: although generally true, there are some cases where using less or more threads than the number of core can be more efficient. And `schedule(dynamic)` is often not that efficient, unless the iterations are either heavily unbalanced or with a quite high workload.

Comment: @PierU in computationally bound code, manually setting the number of threads is wrong 100% of the time, as for the scheduling, unless the work is infinitesimally small (like a single addition), the dynamic scheduler is usually good enough, the static one would invite unneeded crashes, and needs extra planning ahead.

Comment: You assertion *"setting the number of threads num_threads manually **is** wrong,"* is much too strong, as it leaves no room for the cases where it is not wrong. You may write that it is *usually* wrong (i.e. not always). Regarding `dynamic`, although it looks attractive at first, the practical performances are often lower compared to `static`, maybe because of poor implementations in the compilers.